# Chain 3 or more dependent observables

Tags: observable, rxjs6, angular7, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210629/angular-6-pipe-rxjs-operator-to-chain-3-dependant-observables/51210930). But the solution accepted is not working for me or I am not able to understand it well.

I am using ng-7
I have simple use case:

I have 2 APIs, 2nd is dependent on 1st's response.
I subscribe to result of 1st API and then using pipe subscribe to 2nd API result.

My code looks like below;

```
this._SomeService
        .addUserToDb(payload)
        .pipe(
          map(res => res),
          mergeMap(db1Response =>
            this._SomeService.addUserToDb2(db1Response
            )
          ),
          catchError(errodb1 => {

            return Observable.throw(new 
            Error(errorSso));
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          resDb2 => {
              // Here I get response of addUserToDb2
          },
          errDb2 => {


          }
        )
```

Now before subscribing to second API response I want to subscribe to another observable say:

this._tokenService.getToken.pipe(

)

And Want to use it's response in service 2.
Such that:

API1 => token => API2

Please suggest how to implement.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to implement, below is my implementation:

```
  this._service.addUserToDB1(payload).pipe(
          map(resp => this.resDB1 = resp) // Adding to global variable because I need this response while subscribing to DB2 service.
          ,mergeMap(resdb1=>this._tokenService.getToken.pipe(
            mergeMap(token => this._service.addUserToDb2(
              this.resDB1,
              this.organizationId,
              this.practitionerId,
              token
            ),
            catchError(errorToken => {

              return Observable.throw(new Error(errorToken));
            })),
            )
          ),
          catchError(errordb1 => {

            return Observable.throw(new Error(errordb1));
          })

      ).subscribe (
        resdb2Response =>
        {

        },
        errdb2 => {

        }
      )
```

Can someone validate if above implementation is fine or suggest right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**mergeMap** operator is fine here since Api requests emit 1 event and then complete, but to be precise **please use switchMap or concatMap instead of mergeMap**. Please have a look at this post about these operators as well, if you are interested. [RxJs Mapping Operators: switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)

**As for your code block I would suggest something similar which is:**

```
this._service.addUserToDB1(payload).pipe(
  catchError(errordb1 => {
    // do something with error if you want
    return Observable.throw(new Error(errordb1));
  }),
  tap(resp => this.resDB1 = resp),
  switchMap(resdb1 => this._tokenService.getToken),
  catchError(errorToken => {
    // do something with error if you want
    return Observable.throw(new Error(errorToken));
  }),
  switchMap(token => this._service.addUserToDb2(
    this.resDB1,
    this.organizationId,
    this.practitionerId,
    token
  )),
  catchError(errordb2 => {
    // do something with error if you want
    return Observable.throw(new Error(errordb2));
  }),
).subscribe(
  resdb2Response => {

  },
  anyError => {
    // any of the errors will come here
  }
)
```

- `tap()` operator is like just do something and don't change anything to emitted event. Prefer tap over map when you just want to do something, instead of transforming emitted event.

Comment: Goga Koreli Thanks a lot for answering. I have one query, In 'anyerror' we will receive error from received from this._service.addUserToDb2? If yes then why we have cathError block for errordb2?

Comment: @Simer You will receive error from `this._service.addUserToDb2(` but as well from `this._service.addUserToDB1`, so if you want to write logic no matter which error comes up this is the place. Thats why `catchError(errordb2 => {` is still there so that you can write specific logic on that error. If you don't want specific logic for that case you can remove that `catchError` block

Comment: Ok thanks again! So which error we will receive in 'anyError => {
    // any of the errors will come here
  }'? Aren't we going to receive _service.addUserToDb2 errors there only?

Comment: No not only 1 specific, but all of them: eitheir errordb1, errorToken or errordb2, because when the error happens you are not only consuming the error but also re-throwing it as seen for example in `return Observable.throw(new Error(errordb1));`. So inside subscribe as a second parameter we are passing `onError(err)` function which will be called by the runtime when the error is thrown inside Observable. So any of the errors thrown in the Observable will finally arrive here.