# Mergemap - More Than 2 Observables

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, switchmap, mergemap

I got a service method working that would get all of the items from a collection, and merge in user data from a different user collection so that it could easily be displayed on the front end.

I tried to add a third layer of observables to pull and merge another set of data, but it's now just returning observable data to the front end.

This is the call that is working with adding in the users.

```
  getEventList(pid: string, sid: string) {

    return this.afs.collection(this.partyCollectionPath + pid + this.sessionCollectionPath + sid + this.eventCollectionPath,
      ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data({ serverTimestamps: 'estimate' }) as events_list;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;

            return this.afs.doc("users/" + data.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(a => {
             const useData = a.payload.data() as User
             return { id, ...data, user: { ...useData}}
            }))
          })

        }
        ),
        mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs))
      )
  }
```

And this is the code where I tried to add a third layer in to look at the inventoryID from the event. The console.log('iData', iData) isn't actually even hitting, and doesn't even appear in my console when I subscribe to this method so my final return isn't coming through. What did I miss here, can you not add another layer to this?

```
  getEventList(pid: string, sid: string) {

    return this.afs.collection(this.partyCollectionPath + pid + this.sessionCollectionPath + sid + this.eventCollectionPath,
      ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data({ serverTimestamps: 'estimate' }) as events_list;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;

            return this.afs.doc("users/" + data.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(a => {
              const useData = a.payload.data() as User

              return this.afs.doc(this.partyCollectionPath + pid + "/Party-Inventory/" + data.inventoryId).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(b => {
                const iData = b.payload.data() as inventory_list
                console.log('iData', iData)
                return { id, ...data, user: { ...useData }, inventoryData: { ...iData } }
              }))

            }))
          })

        }
        ),
        mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs))
      )
  }
```

**Update**
This is what I got working for this scenario. In the end, I only wanted to run the combineLatest once, so the second mergemap from the answer was absolutely correct, I just needed to move my second internal observable call and final return value in there, which is then picked up by the outer observable mergeMap and combineLatest.

```
  getEventList(pid: string, sid: string) {

return this.afs.collection(this.partyCollectionPath + pid + this.sessionCollectionPath + sid + this.eventCollectionPath,
  ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data({ serverTimestamps: 'estimate' }) as events_list;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        return this.afs.doc("users/" + data.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(a => {
         const useData = a.payload.data() as User

         return { ...useData }
        }), mergeMap( a => {
          return this.afs.doc(this.partyCollectionPath + pid + "/Party-Inventory/" + data.typeId).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(b => {
            const iData = b.payload.data() as inventory_list
            return { id, ...data, user: { ...a }, inventoryData: { ...iData } }
          }))
        }))
      })

    }
    ),
    mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs))
  )
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the two inner observables should also be merged with a [`mergeMap()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) operator. I wrote a small function resembling yours and could not see the actual data when using 3 observables (only observable objects in the console).

Adding another `mergeMap()` within the pipe function where you fetch the specified user document solved the problem on my testing. Here is the sample code I used to test this.

```ts
this.afs.collection('cars', ref => ref.orderBy('model', 'desc')) // Querying documents from a 'cars' collection
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(carDocs => {
          return carDocs.map(car => {
            const carData: any = car.payload.doc.data();

            return this.afs.doc('users/' + carData.owner).snapshotChanges().pipe( // Fetching a specific user document
              map(userDoc => {
                const userData: any = userDoc.payload.data();
                
                return this.afs.doc('inventory/' + carData.name + 'Inventory').snapshotChanges().pipe( // Fetching inventory information
                  map(invEntry => {
                    const invData: any = invEntry.payload.data();
                    return {...carData, ...userData, ...invData};
                  })
                )
              })
            , mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs))) // Merges the two inner observables
          })
        }),
        mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs)) // Adds the outer observable to the combined observable
      ).subscribe(ev => console.log(ev));
```

Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51211003/16929894) discussing a similar implementation. Please let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Did you continue seeing the same behavior in your application?

Comment: It's working a little bit better, but it's returning everything inside of an extra array it seems. It also shows the internal 'combineLatest' as deprecated. I need to look at your example in a little more detail and see if I have something that's a little different because it looks identical to what I want.

Comment: So the data is all coming through correctly when I subscribe, it's just coming through as nested arrays, as opposed to an array with multiple objects:

[{Object1}], [{Object2}] when I would have expected it to be [{Object1}, {Object2}]. I'm going to keep looking to see what could be causing this, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, after tinkering around with your answer I got it working, thank you for your help!